# Tokio subtask within task not executing as expected

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

Although I am new to rust, after having read the rust and tokio books I thought to know how async tasks work. However, obviously I missed something crucial, since I can't seem to be able to resolve the following problem:

I have an async function (asfunc) that needs to poll some sensors indefinitely. For the purposes of demonstration and testing, I created the following stylized function emulating a steady source:

```
async fn asfunc(tx: Sender<String>, name: String) {
    loop {
        thread::sleep( time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        let now = time::Instant::now(); 
        tx.send(format!("[{}] {:?}",name, now)).unwrap();
    }
}
```

I will have to run several of these concurrently form within a main program, and some of these async function will be wrapped in another async function (wrapper()) for post-processing of the data received. Below is the core functionality (it's in a file called th_test.rs):

```
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender; 
use std::{thread, time};

async fn wrapper() {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<String>();
    
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        asfunc(tx,"two".to_string()).await;
    });

    while let Ok(msg) = rx.recv() {
        println!("[wrapper] {:?}",msg);
    }
}

async fn asfunc(tx: Sender<String>, name: String) {
    loop {
        thread::sleep( time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        let now = time::Instant::now(); 
        tx.send(format!("[{}] {:?}",name, now)).unwrap();
    }
}

pub async fn run_test() {    
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<String>();
    
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        asfunc(tx,"one".to_string()).await;
    });

    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        wrapper().await;
    });

    while let Ok(msg) = rx.recv() {
        println!("[asfunc] {:?}",msg);
    }
}
```

And for completeness sake, here is the main.rs file:

```
mod th_test;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {    
    th_test::run_test().await;
}
```

When I run this, I would expect some output from the wrapper function as well, since the code is pretty much identical to what I have in the run_test() function, but what I get is only the output from "directly" calling asfunc:

```
[asfunc] [one] Instant { t: 797790.6589759s }
[asfunc] [one] Instant { t: 797791.6660039s }
[asfunc] [one] Instant { t: 797792.678952s }
...
```

What am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully agree with everything @ChayimFriedman says.

Here is some code to accompany his answer, based on the fact that you say that you **need** to use `std::sync::mpsc`:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use std::time;

async fn wrapper() {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<String>();

    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        asfunc(tx, "two".to_string()).await;
    });

    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        while let Ok(msg) = rx.recv() {
            println!("[wrapper] {:?}", msg);
        }
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}

async fn asfunc(tx: Sender<String>, name: String) {
    loop {
        tokio::time::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        let now = time::Instant::now();
        tx.send(format!("[{}] {:?}", name, now)).unwrap();
    }
}

pub async fn run_test() {
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel::<String>();

    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        asfunc(tx, "one".to_string()).await;
    });

    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        wrapper().await;
    });

    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        while let Ok(msg) = rx.recv() {
            println!("[asfunc] {:?}", msg);
        }
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    run_test().await;
}
```

```
[wrapper] "[two] Instant { tv_sec: 100182, tv_nsec: 4500700 }"
[asfunc] "[one] Instant { tv_sec: 100182, tv_nsec: 4714700 }"
[wrapper] "[two] Instant { tv_sec: 100183, tv_nsec: 5557800 }"
[asfunc] "[one] Instant { tv_sec: 100183, tv_nsec: 5976800 }"
[wrapper] "[two] Instant { tv_sec: 100184, tv_nsec: 7570800 }"
[asfunc] "[one] Instant { tv_sec: 100184, tv_nsec: 7329700 }"
[wrapper] "[two] Instant { tv_sec: 100185, tv_nsec: 8777300 }"
[asfunc] "[one] Instant { tv_sec: 100185, tv_nsec: 9211100 }"
[asfunc] "[one] Instant { tv_sec: 100186, tv_nsec: 11582400 }"
[wrapper] "[two] Instant { tv_sec: 100186, tv_nsec: 11741700 }"
[wrapper] "[two] Instant { tv_sec: 100187, tv_nsec: 13959800 }"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**Never use `thread::sleep()` or `std::sync::mpsc` channels (or any other blocking operation) inside `async fn`.** Use the corresponding `async` primitives: [`tokio::time::sleep()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) and [`tokio::sync::mpsc`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html). [With them, your code works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a393ee5e7c9a0ce13ee4dd4bbbfdde5a).

The exact reason it fails is not clear to me: probably something somewhen blocks all executor threads and it cannot run the task `wrapper()` spawned (I can confirm it doesn't run with a simple `println!()`). But it doesn't matter: you should never block the executor. See [Async: What is blocking?](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately in the real-life equivalent of the asfunc() I need to use an external library which expects as a parameter a std::sync::mpsc::Sender. What I still don't understand, though, is even if I remove the task with the direct asfunc() call from run_test() and only leave the task with the wrapper in there, wrapper still does not print anything. Why should the exact same code work when run from run_test() but not from wrapper()? It must have something to do with the way the task around wrapper is created, but I can't see the reason.

Comment: @PeterK. Scheduler behavior. You should not concern yourself with that, this is an implementation detail. If you _must_ use blocking code, don't use `spawn()` - use [`spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html).

Comment: [`std::sync::mpsc::Sender::send()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#method.send) is **documented as not blocking**, so it by itself is okay to use from async.

Comment: @KevinReid Sure, `Sender` is, but `Sender` needs a receiver too.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman And there are plenty of cases where that is the situation. If you're sending messages to be received by a non-async thread, for example — and Peter's library's use case is likely to be something like that.

Comment: @KevinReid If the library is expecting to get a `Sender` as a parameter then you're probably the receiver, and judging by their example code it is true too. However I think arguing about that in a vaccum is useless.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Did I understand this correctly: if any library uses std::sync::mpsc::Sender as a parameter in an non-terminating function, then that cannot be used in async functions, because async functions cannot safely use the receiver? That surely can't be the case, or can it? In my case, indeed the library expects the std::Sender, and I have control over the receiver. The library internally uses an async websocket to connect to a measuring device. Everything else about the library is a blackbox.

Comment: (Oops, sorry, I misread “expects a Sender” as “provides a Sender”.) @PeterK. You need to either use the receiver in a `spawn_blocking()` function, spawn a thread that receives the messages and resends them on an async channel, or use [`try_recv`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv) to poll it on some schedule of your own (this is appropriate if you have a loop that's predictably running anyway; otherwise it's wasteful).

Comment: @PeterK. You don't have to do all the work in sync code: you can spawn a little blocking task that just bridges between the sync and the async, gets messages from the sync channel and sends them to an async channel.

Comment: I think the reason it works in one configuration and not in another is just chance ... I think as soon as it gets stuck in a `rx.recv()` with no data in the channel yet, it gets stuck forever. In the other configuration it just happens to execute the tasks in the order that an item always gets put into the channel first before calling `recv()`. That's at least my guess.